# How to link a button to an action

Tags: ios, ibaction

I have experience in C++ and I need to know how to make a button goto a void method I have created.

This is basically what my button is

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
}
```

If there is not a way to do so then is there a way to link a button to an alert view?

I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: If one of the below answers helped you, don't forget to tick the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender` is defined in your `@interface`, then in Interface Builder, right-click+drag from your Button object to **File's Owner**, then choose **`Button:`** *(your IBAction)*.

[image]

### Show alert inside `IBAction`

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some title" message:@"Some message." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    [_alert setTag:1];
    [_alert show];
    [_alert release];
}
```

Comment: You can also hold down the `control` key and drag.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
UIButton *myButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0f , 720.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)myButtonTapped:(id)iSender {
    //Code For Button Action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/* UIButton programmatically from a IBAction */
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];

-(IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"New Button Clicked");
}
```